# JavaFx Running a While Loop Parallel to the GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx

So, I am creating a JavaFx game application and it is necessary to run a while loop while having the GUI open and running. This is easily achieved using swing however with JavaFx the application must close before any of my code is implemented. Is there a way to run the loop run parallel to the GUI or must I revert to swing? Is it possible to trigger the loop through an event and still have the application respond to other events?

Comment: *"however with JavaFx the application must close before any of my code is implemented"* Could you please reformulate this. It doesn't seem to make much sense, since you usually don't implement something at runtime. Also it's unclear what's the exact issue you're facing (i.e. why do you think running things in parallel does not work in javafx; what exactly goes wrong?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for Concurrent task in JavaFX. Create a new task to run the loop and execute it in a new Thread.

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {
        static final int max = 1000000;
        for (int i=1; i<=max; i++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
               break;
            }
            updateProgress(i, max);
        }
        return null;
    }
};

new Thread(task).start();
```

Refer - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

If you need any actions to be taken once the task is completed, add them to On Succeeded method of Task.